# Is there a JS "scope block" with object?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object as such:

```
var Root = {
    A: {
        AA: ...,
        AB: ...,
        AC: function() {}
    }
};
```

Is there syntax in JS that supports a "scope block" or something similar, like in pseudo-code, such that I could call the function `AC()` or get the value `AB` without having to redundantly write `Root.A`?

**Something like this**

```
(Root.A) {
    AC();
    console.log(AB);
}
```

**to mean something like this**

```
Root.A.AC();
console.log(Root.A.AB);
```

Comment: You're looking for [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), but it's extremely discouraged (as that documentation explains).

Comment: Why do you have "A"? You could just use var Root = {...}

Comment: It appears that the documentation is largely concerned with ambiguity.  More out of curiosity, if literally (for argument's sake) all of the JS functionality were contained under `Root.A` in this case, does it remove the issue of using `with`?

Comment: @NoChance to show the point, it's not actual code obviously

Comment: @4castle I did not know that.  Thanks for the tid-bit.  Removed the tag.

Comment: There is no such thing like a *"JSON object"*. [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a text representation of some data structure. The code you posted is **the** data structure, a regular JavaScript object. The usual JavaScript scoping rules apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some version on (ES6 I think) you can use a destructuring assignment and write something like this:

```
const {AA, AB, AC} = Root.A;
AC();
console.log(AB);
```

If that helps.

Comment: Any reason not to use this, as with the `with`?

Comment: The only reason I could think of is that you need to support javascript prior version ES6.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no recommended way of achieving this. We have the `with` statement, which does exactly what you need it to, but it comes with performance costs and it is explicitly prohibited in `strict mode` (explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Simplifying_variable_uses)).

If for some reason you absolutely need this functionality, you would use `with` like so:

```js
var Root = {
    A: {
        AA: 5,
        AB: 6,
        AC: function() {return 4;}
    }
};

with(Root.A) {

    console.log(AB);
    console.log(AA);

    console.log( AC() );
}
```

Edit:

Another way of doing this (also unrecommended) would be to add `Root.A` to the global window scope like so:

```js
var Root = {
    A: {
        AA: 5,
        AB: 6,
        AC: function() {return 3;}
    }
};

// Extend window with Root.A's objects
window = Object.assign(window, Root.A);

console.log(AA);
console.log(AB);
console.log( AC() );
```

The tradeoff with the solution above is that you are polluting the global scope (a very bad idea).

Lastly, if you know all of the fields of `Root.A` ahead of time, you can simply assign the fields to variables in the current scope with the same name:

```js
var Root = {
    A: {
        AA: 5,
        AB: 6,
        AC: function() {return 3;}
    }
};

(function() {
  
  var AA = Root.A.AA;
  var AB = Root.A.AB;
  var AC = Root.A.AC;
  
  console.log(AA);
  console.log(AB);
  console.log( AC() );
  
})();
```

This last way would be the preferred way of doing it, but it assumes you know all of the field names ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the function references the outer object if that is what you are looking for.

```js
var Root = {
    A: {
        AA: 1234,
        AB: 'AB text',
        AC: function() {
           // this ==== Root
           return this.AB;
        }
    }
};

console.log(Root.A.AC())
```